# Error marshalling arguments

Tags: java

I have a code like this

```
Class Base implements java.io.Serializable, Cloneable
{
}

Class Derived extends Base
{
  private Aclass class;
}
```

The Class AClass **does not implement**  java.io.Serializable

I am passing `Base b = (Base) d;` to a remote method. And I am getting an error 
**"java.rmi.MarshalException" occured.  Exception message is "error marshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.io.NotSerializableException: Aclass "**

I understand objects passed as parameters to remote methods must either be Serializable or 
Exported remote objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must implement the `Serializable` interface in all the classes that you want to marshal. You could also skip some elements from marshaling using `transient` keyword. The attributes marked with `transient` are not serialized in Java.

Answer (score 2):

Neither your Base or Derived classes implement the private methods all concrete Serializable clases [must implement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html):

> Classes that require special handling during the serialization and
>   deserialization process must implement special methods with these
>   exact signatures:

```
private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream out)
    throws IOException
private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in)
    throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException;
private void readObjectNoData()
    throws ObjectStreamException;
```